# node.js mongodb filter based on date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In node.js from mongodb collection, how do I filter documents of a collection based on the `date_added` field as previous year, previous week and previous month? The `date_added` field is in `ISO Date`  Format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"),
    "title" : "car",
    "price" : 100,
    "date_added" : ISODate("2016-06-01T04:47:33.025Z"),

}
```

Comment: what did you already did in this direction?

Comment: @profesor79 to me the best way to proceed is by using $lt but the question arises what with what should I compare the date_added filed, as here I cant use hard coded data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is to use `moment.js`
Do `npm install moment`

```
var moment = require ('moment')

 function previous_year_artist(req, res, next) {
        var dateTimeTofilter = moment().subtract(1, 'year');
        var filter = {
            "date_added": {
                $gte: new Date(dateTimeTofilter._d)
            }
        };
        db.collection.find(
            filter
        ).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(result);
        });

    }
```

use `year,month, week` as per your requirment

Comment: I don't think this is the best way in 2020, add a library only for this simple operation?!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a variable in node.js named `dateTimeTofilter`

```
var week = 7,
    year =365,
    month = 31; // this values you need to calculate and then use in query


var dateTimeTofilter =  new Date() - week;
var filter = {"date_added": { $lte: dateTimeTofilter }}; 
                            // or $gte- depends on time windows

var cursor = db.collection('collectionName').find(filter);

cursor.forEach(
    function(doc) {
           //process data here
          }
```